# How apply lambda to each dataframe row so it tests two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataset with two columns: in the first column, the full directory path of a file.  In the second column, the date the file was last modified.  I am trying to figure out the number of files in each upper level folder ("dog", "feline", "mouse", "anteater") that were last modified later than 2004-06-23.  Ultimately, I'd like something like this:

[image: dog]

Here's my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'FullName': ["dog\cat\cow\rover.doc","feline\cat\cow\digger.doc","dog\cat\cow\whatamess.doc","mouse\cat\mouse\jude.doc","anteater\cat\mouse\sam.doc","dog\cat\owl\audrey.doc",
], 'LastWriteTime': ['2003-01-02', '2004-01-02', '2005-01-02','2006-01-02','2007-01-02','2008-01-02']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I can count the number of times the upper level folder recurs in the dataset:

`df2 = (df1['FullName'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\\')[0]).value_counts()`

I can also count the number of times files with a date greater than '2004-06-23' recurs in the dataset:

`df3 = df1['LastWriteTime'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime((x),yearfirst=True) > pd.to_datetime('2004-06-23',yearfirst=True)).value_counts()`

I tried to combine them as follows:

```
df2 = (df1['FullName'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\\')[0]) & pd.to_datetime((x),yearfirst=True) > pd.to_datetime('2004-06-23',yearfirst=True)).value_counts()
```

but I get the error code: `x is not defined`

Does anyone know how to combine them?

Comment: Just a reminder, At "dog\cat\cow\rover.doc" you have \r which is escape sequence. Use  r"dog\cat\cow\rover.doc" or use / instead of \. Python recognizes it. also for \audrey.doc.

Comment: thanks!  I was wondering why that wasn't working.

Comment: Did it work? It's not working in my end, for some reason.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - when I saw your note I added double slashes: "dog\\cat\\cow\\rover.doc"

Comment: just a reminder, I recommend using r rather than escaping backslashes - as it looks [cleaner](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/StackOverFlow/blob/master/62724370.py)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use expression. Refer python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Just wrap it in parentheses and python interpreter is happy about it.

```
lambda x: (x.split('\\')[0]) & (pd.to_datetime(x, yearfirst=True) > pd.to_datetime('2004-06-23',yearfirst=True)))
```

However, you are applying function to respective table 'LastWriteTime' and 'FullName', function suits better. Create multiple evaluation functions and store it in dict with corresponding keys, and pass to aggregate().

```
def check_date(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x) > pd.to_datetime('2004-06-23', yearfirst=True)


def files_count(x):
    return x.split('\\')[0]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

func_dict = {'FullName': files_count, 'LastWriteTime': check_date}

df4 = df1.aggregate(func_dict)  # applying multiple function to multiple columns
print(df4, end='\n'*2)

# use df[df['a']] & df[df['b']] for filtering.
df3_filtered = df4[df4['LastWriteTime']]  # filtering.
print(df3_filtered, end='\n'*2)

df2 = df3_filtered['FullName'].value_counts()  # counting.
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
   FullName  LastWriteTime
0       dog          False
1    feline          False
2       dog           True
3     mouse           True
4  anteater           True
5       dog           True

   FullName  LastWriteTime
2       dog           True
3     mouse           True
4  anteater           True
5       dog           True

dog         2
anteater    1
mouse       1
Name: FullName, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you very much - the second piece of code works fantastic

Comment: Glad it helped, was a good chance to use pandas for first time.